# Fastest way to mark duplicate records in a large database table

Tags: php, mysql

Im looking for the best solution of a large data problem. I've been thinking for a while now and its nice to hear your opinion.

I have a mysql database with a table that has about 5.000.000 records that is loaded and daily changed (new records and changed records).

There are some duplicated records in that table that i want mark daily.

There are arround 20 columns in the table. I want to find duplicated records that have the same data in 4 of the columns of the table.

Afther that i found the duplicates i need to loop through each duplicate record to update my search function and update the record in the table that it is duplicated to the other product.

I want to use mysql resources little as possible and make the script as fast as possible.

Now i have the following query but it is realy slow:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '|') as ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT(stock SEPARATOR '|') as stock
FROM table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4
HAVING count(id) > 1;
```

I could put indexes on the for columns but i think it will still be slow to run this query.

I'm curious about your vision.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query We don't need to see 20 columns if the point can be effectively conveyed in 5 or 6

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a query like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4,
       group_concat(id separator '|') as ids,
       group_concat(stock separator '|') as stocks
from stock s
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
having count(*) > 1;
```

(This is essentially your query.  It is where I would start, though.)

Alternatively, it might be faster to get each duplicated row.  You can do this by using:

```
select s.*
from stock s
where exists (select 1
              from stock s2
              where s2.col1 = s.col1 and s2.col2 = s.col2 and
                    s2.col3 = s.col3 and s2.col4 = s.col4 and
                    s2.id <> s.id
             );
```

For this to have any hope of working, you need an index on `stock(col1, col2, col3, col4, id)`.  And this formulation assumes the values in those columns are not `NULL`.

Note:  If this is faster but you still need the original format, you can put this condition into the `group by` query.

To be honest, though.  I think the right approach is to have a unique index on the four columns:

```
create index unq_stock_col1_col2_col3_col4 on stock(col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

Then handle the duplicate problems when `update`s or `insert`s modify the data.  It is best to do data integrity checks in the database and to not let the data problems get out-of-hand.

Comment: I first tried the alternatively query that u suggested. Oddly enough it takes the same time as my old query.
My old query avg: 60.026384115219
Your query: 60.062566995621

Comment: i will try the indexes now. what is the best way, one index for the four columns or an index on each column?

Comment: @BoPennings . . . one index on all five columns, as specified.

Comment: . . . strange.. i've added the index on the 5 columns but it doesnt help at all. The query still takes 60.6 seconds. Now i even think that the 60 seconds is the maximum of my php script. Afther the 60 seconds when the script is complete the query is still shown up in the mysql processlist on the state 'sending data'

Comment: @BoPennings . . . The issue could be the number of rows that are duplicated.  You can throw a `count(*)` on the second query to see how many are duplicated and how long it takes to calculate that number.